# .ipa application crashes, but not build application from xCode

Tags: ios

If I build my application in xCode and run directly in iPAD mini, it runs successfully. Even if, I restarts the application.

But, if I archive the build and run the .ipa AdHoc release in the same iPAD mini, my .ipa application crashes during use.

Crash report shows the Mellor like :
**Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x17d902af
Triggered by Thread:  0**

Is there any settings needed, during .ipa AdHoc release ?

Please advice.

Suvendu

Comment: Add something like `Crashlytics` into your project to get crash reports for your crash, it's difficult to answer from the informations you have provided. Normally there is not difference in any IPA you make except the different Provisioning Profiles and Certificates involved. It is your app which is breaking at some condition. [Go here](https://fabric.io) and follow steps to add into your application, it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I`m looking into how to add Crashlytics into my project to get the detailed crash report